# ePub converter that saves in HTML5?

Tags: epub, conversion, html

Does anyone have an ePub converter that actually saves in HTML5? 
I have tried Kotobee Author and Calibre but they save in HTML 4/XHTML. An update of the Mozilla Composer/SeaMonkey IDE (Internet Developer Environment) came out in Feb. 2018 but that also saves in HTML 4. 
A lot of IDEs and ePub apps claim to support HTML5 but save to HTML 4.
Any suggestions?
I don't want to manually migrate my code to HTML5 and then have the ePub converter wrap it as HTML 4. Or am I making too big a deal of this?
Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Sigil](https://github.com/Sigil-Ebook/Sigil/releases/tag/0.9.9) supports both epub2 and epub3 books and one of the Sigil developers has published a [plugin](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?p=2973066) that'll convert epub2 books to epub3 books.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Pandoc. I am not sure how "correct" is the HTML5...

```
$ pandoc file.epub -t html5 -s > file.html
```

Pandoc is open source. `sudo apt install pandoc` if not previously installed.

Without `-s` just the `body`'s content is generated.
(Several options available to control html output)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Kitaboo](https://kitaboo.com/) it can convert to epub3 as well as html5